# Communicating between 2 different local subnets

Tags: networking

I have the following equipments & specifications

- 1 Mac OS
- 1 Windows XP
- 1 Linksys Cisco WRT600N router

My Mac OS will be on a local subnet (example 192.168.1.0/24), and my Windows XP will be on another local subnet (example 192.168.2.0/24).

How am I supposed to configure my router in order for both of my 2 subnets (Mac OS & Windows XP) to "talk" to each other ?

On another note, I would also like my MAC OS IP address to be dynamically assigned from the router (DHCP server for this subnet), while my Windows XP IP address can be statically assigned.

Could I get some helps/tips/suggestions here ?

Comment: You should ask this on [su].  If you do, please delete this question; cross-posting is strongly discouraged.

Comment: How did you configured the second subnet? Does this router support multiple VLANs? What is the meaning of '"talk" to each other"? Also, if you'll explain the need that brought you to use separate subnets, someone might offer another way to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you do not need any config for communication between your Mac OS and Windows XP. I assume that you configure router's port connecting to Mac OS in 192.168.1.0/24 subnet and the port connecting to Windows XP in the subnet 192.168.2.0/24.

In this case, the router's Routing table will have "Direct" routes to both the subnets(192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24).

I do not know how to configure DHCP server on Cisco Linksys, but it is possible to configure DHCP server on one network only.